# Why is Copy constructor being called only when we return *this?

Tags: c++

```
Class Cents(){  
 int m_val;  
 public:  
  Cents(int x=0){ cout<<"Constructor";}
  Cents(const Cents& src){ cout<<"Copy constructor"}
  Cents Add(int val){m_val=val; return *this}  // --->(1)
 }
```

Assume I have `Cents object obj` and am calling `obj.Add()`

Now the output will be

> Constructor
>   Copy constructor

So my assumption was Here by returning `*this` in (1) we are copying the `*this` object value to a new temporary Cents object. That's why copy constructor is called.

Now if I replace line (1) with

```
Cents Add(int val){ Cents temp;return temp;}  // --->(2)
```

the only output is

> Constructor

Why is the copy constructor not being called?  Is my assumption about line (1) wrong?

Comment: Please provide a code that uses your `Cents` class, I don't see any constructor call in your code snippet

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: The example is the `Add` function, 2nd version, which (in principle) returns a copy of the local variable `temp`.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan>Below is the code snippet .Object creation part I have just told in words.I guess thats why you couldnt figure out.Below is few parts of the code .For the 2nd program code pls replace the line (1) with this line Cents Add(int val){ Cents temp;return temp;} .Rest of the code is same.                  Class Cents(){  
 int m_val;  
 public:  
  Cents(int x=0){ cout<<"Constructor";}
  Cents(const Cents& src){ cout<<"Copy constructor"}
  Cents Add(int val){m_val=val; return *this}  // --->(1)
 } int main(){ Cents obj;obj.Add(10));}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an optimisation known as *copy elision*, sometimes called "(N)RVO" (for "(named) return value optimisation") by those who like acronyms.

In certain circumstances, when an object is (conceptually) created in one place, copied or moved to another, and then destroyed, the program is allowed to create it in its final place instead. This optimisation is allowed even if the elided constructor and/or destructor have side effects, as they do in your example.

Returning a temporary, or a local variable, from a function is one of these situations. Instead of creating `temp` in the function's stack frame then copying it to the caller's, the program may instead create it directly in the caller's frame.

When you return `*this`, the copy can't be elided, since `*this` has a lifetime beyond the function. From the caller's point of view, there will be two objects, so the program must actually make a copy:

```
Cents original;
Cents copy = original.Add(42);

// "copy" and "original" both exist: the object must have been copied.
```

For full details of which operations can be elided by this optimisation, see the C++11 Standard, 12.8/31.

Comment: >So you meant to say Copy ellision technique doesnt applies for Cents obj = *this.and for Cents obj = some temporary object ,C++ compiler will enable copy ellision.Actually i didnt understand what you meant by statement "When you return *this, the copy can't be elided".And if you dont mind,Could you pls tell in layman langauage.Because this statement is the exact anwser to my question.

Comment: @Poorvi: I've added a bit more detail about why `return *this` can't be elided. The function must create a second object, separate from `*this`, so it must really be copied.

Comment: >ooh that means ,since because *this has a lifetime even after that Add function,compiler is not omitting *this,So it copies *this value to temporary Cents object like this {returning Cents temporary object here }Add() = *this.While in the other case ,we are copying a local Cents object temp to a Cents temporary object.So compiler is calling constructor for Cents temp statement and initialising it directly .hence omitting copy constructor call ie since because both are temporary variables,its just doing a constructor call thats it.Am i got it correct?

Comment: @Poorvi: That's right. The temporary or local can be created directly in the caller's stack frame so that it's available after the function returns without the need to copy it. The function isn't creating `*this`, so it has to create a new object to be the return value.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because most of the compilers perform [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (aka RVO) to save on copying.