# Copy constructor - Understanding problems

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

i have some problems understanding C++ copy constructors, I hope someone could help me.

As far as I know, the copy constructor is called (among others things) when a function returns an instance of a class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    int a;
public:
    Test(int a) : a(42) 
    {}

    // Copy constructor
    Test(const Test& other) 
    {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
};

Test test_function()
{
    Test a(3);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    test_function();
    return 0;
}
```

So, if I execute this code, the copy constructor never gets called? Why? And which object is than returned?

Furthermore, if I replace the line

```
test_function();
```

to

```
Test b = test_function();
```

the copy constructor is neither called - why not?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
When changing the function to:

```
Test test_function()
{
    Test a(3);
    Test b(34);

    if (4 < 2)
        return a;

    else
        return b;
}
```

one can see the copy constructor call, since the compiler is not able to use RVO.

Comment: It's an optimization called "Named return value optimization", NRVO for short.

Comment: There is a single Test object in this example, to see copyconstructors in action you need at least 2 objects. Like Test b = test_function()

Comment: The compiler correctly observes that you don't use the returned value (in neither case) and it optimizes the copy away. Copy elision is the only optimization that's allowed to alter the observable behaviour of a program.

Comment: @jrok My guess is that it's more likely to be NRVO. [IDEOne seems to agree](http://ideone.com/9x0bYm).

Comment: @Dukeling: You're using the returned value then NRVO will be applied. jrok's comment is about omitting return value totally due to unused return value.

Comment: @MM. Exactly my point - the copy constructor still isn't getting called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Copy constructor being called only when we return \*this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252679/why-is-copy-constructor-being-called-only-when-we-return-this)

Comment: Thank you for the hints regarding NRVO, that explains a lot!
I came to this question because I thought and tried about how to return an instance of a class.
As I see in your answers, the way I did it in the example is correct - isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's (copy/move) constructor elision as an optimization to avoid unnecessary copies/moves. Another optimization can be applied is totally to ignore returning anything since you're not using the returned value at all.

Anyway, you can disable this optimization and see the message you want by this compiler switch (gcc):

```
-fno-elide-constructors
```

But, use above switch only for tests and let the optimization applies in real programs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test test_function()
{
    Test a(3);
    return a;
}
```

This function is declaring a local copy of `Test` and returning it.  The compiler will see that, realize that it is about to destroy the local copy as it creates a new copy, and simply elides the local copy to the result.  To see the result you want, this may work better:

```
Test test_function(const Test& t)
{
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    Test t2 = test_function(t1);
    return 0;
}
```